# scikit-learn ValueError: operands could not be broadcast together with shapes

Tags: python, numpy, scikit-learn

I'm getting an error which almost always points to features being in the wrong format (wrong # of features), but I've checked and that's definitely not the issue.

```
model = RandomForestClassifier(warm_start=True)

...
# Train
print('Training on', X_train.shape)
model.fit(X_train, y_train)

...

# Test
print('Predicting on', X_test.shape)
return model.predict(X_test)
```

The output:

```
Training on (118808, 24)
Predicting on (3539, 24)

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "{myfilesystem}/model.py", line 352, in score
    y_pred = self.y_scaler.inverse_transform(self.backend(X_pred).reshape(-1, 1))
  File "{myfilesystem}/model.py", line 176, in __call__
    return self.model.predict(X)
  File "{myfilesystem}/.venv/lib/python3.10/site-packages/sklearn/ensemble/_forest.py", line 820, in predict
    proba = self.predict_proba(X)
  File "{myfilesystem}/.venv/lib/python3.10/site-packages/sklearn/ensemble/_forest.py", line 873, in predict_proba
    Parallel(n_jobs=n_jobs, verbose=self.verbose, require="sharedmem")(
  File "{myfilesystem}/.venv/lib/python3.10/site-packages/sklearn/utils/parallel.py", line 63, in __call__
    return super().__call__(iterable_with_config)
  File "{myfilesystem}/.venv/lib/python3.10/site-packages/joblib/parallel.py", line 1085, in __call__
    if self.dispatch_one_batch(iterator):
  File "{myfilesystem}/.venv/lib/python3.10/site-packages/joblib/parallel.py", line 901, in dispatch_one_batch
    self._dispatch(tasks)
  File "{myfilesystem}/.venv/lib/python3.10/site-packages/joblib/parallel.py", line 819, in _dispatch
    job = self._backend.apply_async(batch, callback=cb)
  File "{myfilesystem}/.venv/lib/python3.10/site-packages/joblib/_parallel_backends.py", line 208, in apply_async
    result = ImmediateResult(func)
  File "{myfilesystem}/.venv/lib/python3.10/site-packages/joblib/_parallel_backends.py", line 597, in __init__
    self.results = batch()
  File "{myfilesystem}/.venv/lib/python3.10/site-packages/joblib/parallel.py", line 288, in __call__
    return [func(*args, **kwargs)
  File "{myfilesystem}/.venv/lib/python3.10/site-packages/joblib/parallel.py", line 288, in <listcomp>
    return [func(*args, **kwargs)
  File "{myfilesystem}/.venv/lib/python3.10/site-packages/sklearn/utils/parallel.py", line 123, in __call__
    return self.function(*args, **kwargs)
  File "{myfilesystem}/.venv/lib/python3.10/site-packages/sklearn/ensemble/_forest.py", line 653, in _accumulate_prediction
    out[0] += prediction
ValueError: operands could not be broadcast together with shapes (2656,30) (2656,32) (2656,30)
```

This **only** happens with classification models - changing the `RandomForestClassifier` to `RandomForestRegressor` results in code that runs as expected. I can't think of a reason why a classifier would fail in this way when the regressor works perfectly, especially when none of # of features mentioned (30 and 32) are the number of features in the input dataset.